# How to solve "Name field is required" in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, data-annotations

Iam getting the following error when posting the form with ProductVM fields:

[image]

This is the model being passed:

```
[BindProperties]
public class ProductVM
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;

    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the form:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductVM>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                </td>
                <form asp-action="AddToCart">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Name">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Price">
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@item.Quantity" value="1" class="form-control" style="inline-size:100px">
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="addtocart" value="Add To Cart" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
    }
```

Any ideas why the name field is throwing error even with the "input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Name"" ?

Comment: It is marked [Required] in the model.

Comment: I know, I want to keep the [Required] and still be able to submit the form.

Comment: It has to be populated with a value.  You can put some dummy value in there for now.  It may be possible with js to remove the validation attributes after the page has loaded.

Comment: Hi @Cohiba, Model Binding binds the property by name attribute. You can F12 in browser and check the name, you can see it should be `name="item.propertyName"`. One way is to add `[Bind(prefix="item")]` to specific the prefix. Another way is you can use for loop to specify the `name="[i].propertyName"`. Besides, you use `<form asp-action="AddToCart">` without specify the method, it will get into the get action by default,  could you pls share how is your action like? And what is the parameter like for this action?

Answer (score 0):

foreach loop is not submiting data back, you have to use for loop

```
 @foreach (var i=0, i< Model.Count; i++) {

  .....
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id">
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Name">
    ...

}
```